# Put footer at the bottom HTML relative position

Tags: html, css

The footer of my website is not working properly, I need it to be always stick at the bottom of page.

Things I have tried :

1. `position:relative` : works best for most of the pages except when min-height is less than some value after which I saw like this, blank space below footer.

[image]

2. `position:absolute` with `bottom:0`: though footer is at the bottom always, but doesn't take care of content (because content is `position:relative`) which gave me something like this i.e footer doesn't consider content height.

[image]

So my question here is : Is there any pure CSS way of achieving the footer always at the bottom with `position:relative` on `footer`.

Comment: try `postion:absolute; bottom: 0px;`

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Can you give us the site? or show us some code? So it's easyer to help you

Comment: @Aatif: Its not working .. not considering the content (which is `position:relative`) and footer is floating in the content. Read question carefully.

Comment: is there a reason why you dont use position: fixed; for this?

Comment: @Rudi : Its giving me result like 1st case.

Comment: You have to also assign bottom: 0; than it should work position fixed releases the element from any positioning convention and always places it in relation to your screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called Sticky footer approach. Try this code, it works on all browsers. In case of responsive website, you need to manage it via breakpoints

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  /* equal to footer height */
}
header {
  background: #ccc;
}
footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>something</header>
<footer>this will stay at bottom always</footer>
```

Comment: Its not working on firefox ...with `bottom:0`. Any suggestions.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/happy2deepak/2e3ad9c8cd5c4abd7dd867c6de3791a7 - Try this link. It has the required Jquery as well. If still doesn't works, check your code, something might be missing

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox, this should be the way you solve this:

## The HTML

```
<body class="Site">
  <header>…</header>
  <main class="Site-content">…</main>
  <footer>…</footer>
</body>
```

## The CSS

```
.Site {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.Site-content {
  flex: 1;
}
```